# Gitlab CI automatic deploy using rsync and sshpass

Tags: deployment, rsync, gitlab-ci, sshpass

I have problem with my autodeploy on gitlab-ci. I want send files from docker run on runner to remote host (my site hosting).
My `.gitlab-ci.yml` is like this

```
variables:
# STAGING CONFIGURATION
  STAGING_USER: "test@test.com"
  STAGING_URL: "test.com"
# $STAGING_SSH_PASSWORD - configure in gilab->settings->CI/CD->variables

# image with php an
image: webdevops/php-apache-dev:5.6

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq sshpass
  - apt-get install zip unzip
  - apt-get install -y ssh
  - mkdir ~/.ssh
  - echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> ~/.ssh/config
  - apt-get install -y rsync

# DEPLOY STAGING
DEPLOY_STAGING:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - export SSHPASS=$STAGING_SSH_PASSWORD
    - rsync -hrvz -e sshpass -e  theme/ $STAGING_USER:~/test/
```

But when I try with this configuration I getting error

`rsync: Failed to exec theme/: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(85) [Receiver=3.1.2]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(235) [Receiver=3.1.2]
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`

I don't have idea how configure this correctly. I must auth via sshpass because my server don't allow rsa auth.

Answer (score 1):

In the manual page for sshpass I found this example:

```
rsync --rsh='sshpass -p 12345 ssh -l test' host.example.com:path .
```

https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the rsync ssh shell parameter into quotes:

```
rsync -hrvz -e "sshpass -e" theme/ $STAGING_USER:~/test/
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but this isn't work for me. Now I getting error like this.
`sshpass: invalid option -- 'l'
protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(178) [sender=3.1.2]`

Maybe you have other idea for this problem ?